# Apply condicional to an AJAX xml parse

Tags: jquery, ajax, conditional-statements

I'm triying to apply an "if" condition to an AJAX xml parse, but i can't. This is my code

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
     {
          $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://domain.com/file.xml",
          dataType: "xml",
          success: function(xml) {

                 $(xml).find("something").each(function(){
                         if (data[i]["somefield"] == 1) {
                                $("#output").append("HOLAAAA");
                         } else {
                                $("#output").append("MOLOOOOOOOOOO");
                         }

                  });
          },
          error: function() {
                 alert("Can't retrieve data");
          }

          });

     });
</script>
```

But it doesn't run. Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: What you try to do isn't clear but you probably should use the arguments passed to the callback you give to each : `$(xml).find("something").each(function(SOME ARGS){`.

Comment: Where is `i` declared??..Pass it through jquery `each` function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine your `data[i]` is your attempt to access the current `"something"` node inside the loop.

Inside your callback, you should access the current node through `this` :

```
  // if "somefield" is an attribute :
  if ($(this).attr("somefield") == 1) {
       $("#output").append("HOLAAAA");
  } else {
       $("#output").append("MOLOOOOOOOOOO");
  }

  // if "somefield" is a child node :
  if ($(this).children("somefield").text() == 1) {
       $("#output").append("HOLAAAA");
  } else {
       $("#output").append("MOLOOOOOOOOOO");
  }
```